# Recommendation based on implicit feedback - Spark Mlib

Tags: apache-spark, logistic-regression, apache-spark-mllib, collaborative-filtering

I have implicit feedback from users about their interaction with different products. Following is the structure of dataset:  user_id, product_category, event_date,view_count,purchase_count

Based on this data I am trying to predict a score for a user's affinity to a product category. MLIB implicit form expects the input dataset of the format Rating(user: Int, product: Int, rating: Double). But how do I include view_count and purchase_count ?

If MLLIB can't be used is there any other method I can use. My product categories are limited (only 8 product categories). In that case can I use 8 logistic regression models to predict affinity ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing is called [multinomial logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) which is used for [multiclass classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification).  This is a generalization of the typical [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) which has only 2 outcomes (binary).

It looks like you were trying to apply a [collaborative filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering) model which won't work in this case as you have pointed out.

Check out the Spark ML/MLlib docs for [multinomial logistic regression](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#logistic-regression).

You would treat each of the inputs (view_count and purchase_count) as separate features (input data) to train the model using existing, known data including the outcomes.

When you score/predict on new data, the model will return a probability for each of the possible outcomes:  8, in this case ... 1 for each of the product categories.  Then choose the category with the highest probability.

Below are some relevant Spark Documentation links:

**Spark's Logistic Regression Programming Guide**

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#logistic-regression

**Current spark.mllib Logistic Regression API**

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics

**New spark.ml Logistic Regression API**

(Note:  this only supports binary, logistic regression right now, but you should migrate to this when it's available)

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

Comment: thank you for the response. One challenge with using single logistic regression model is - the outcome is not mutually exclusive. For example, let the dependent variable is defined as  purchases of product categories in the next 7 days and customer would have made  purchases in multiple categories. Is there an approach I can use in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to predict affinity score or go ahead with recommendation based on affinity? For example, you might have a ratio of purchase to visit, keep that as rating (affinity rating here) and perform recommendation

Comment: I am trying to predict affinity score for each product category.I don't need the recommendations now.